# How can I change the like counter in real time based on what I'm receiving in the response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

The backend calls to increment likes depicted by `handleLike()` and `handleLike()` functions successfully return the response of containing the number that's been incremented/decremented.

Unfortunately, this is the only way I can see `photos.likes` incremented/decrement in real time.

My question is: How do I make it so that I able to only increment/decrement the likes amount by `1` for the specific image's `UserID` that's being clicked on instead of ALL of them.  Also, is there a way to avoid using frontend logic to accomplish this since the increment/decrement is happening on the server side?

I've hit a wall on this and not sure how to overcome it.

**Note:** I've included the hook `respLikes` but not using it anywhere as I'm simply leaving it here in case it'd be needed to accomplish this.  The `console.logs()` beneath them display the correct incrementation/decrementation.

```
const [currentUserClicks, setCurrentUserClicks]               = useState(1);
const [onChangeLikes, setonChangeLikes]                       = useState(null);
const [respLikes, setRespLikes]                               = useState(null);

const handleLike = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    const url = 'http://localhost/api/like';

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    let data = {
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId,
        'likeCount': currentUserClicks
    };

    axios.post(url, data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            setRespLikes(resp.data.userLikes[0].likes);
            // console.log("handleLike",resp.data.userLikes[0].likes);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
    });

};

const handleDisLike = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    const url = 'http://localhost/api/dislike';

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    let data = {
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId,
        'likeCount': currentUserClicks
    };

    axios.post(url, data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            setRespLikes(resp.data.userLikes[0].likes);
            // console.log("handleDisLike", resp.data.userLikes[0].likes);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

};

const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
        if(currentUserClicks > 1) {
            setCurrentUserClicks(currentUserClicks - 1);
            handleDisLike(likedPhotoUserId); // sends data to server to decrement DB column
            setonChangeLikes(false);
        } else {
            setCurrentUserClicks(currentUserClicks + 1); 
            handleLike(likedPhotoUserId); // sends data to server to increment DB column
            setonChangeLikes(true);
        }
    };


return(
{
 data.map((photos, index) => {
   return <>
     <div key={index}>
       <img src={photos.url} alt="Photo" className="gallery-img" onClick={() => handleLikesBasedOnUserId(photos.UserID)}/>
       <h5 className="likes">Likes: {!onChangeLikes ? photos.likes - 1: photos.likes + 1}</h5>      
     </div>
   </>
  })
}
);
```

Comment: Via the backend are you ultimately updating the `photos.likes` value of the `data` array that is being mapped? Can you share what `data` is?

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the `Photo` component and handle the click-action with API call in there. In the extracted `Photo` component, `likes` would be a parameter and `currentLikes` a state variable (with `likes` as default value) that is used for rendering. On API response, you can then just call `setCurrentLikes`.

Extracting sub components most often helps with this kind of state issues.